# words that have same first and last characters in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to select words that have same first and last characters in the list below using `Python` :

I know I need to use random_strings but I don't know how.

`['xerox', 'trust', 'follow', 'blurb', 'maroon', 'ready', 'salad', 'yummy', 'evidence']`

I am looking for this result:

`['xerox', 'trust', 'blurb', 'yummy', 'evidence']`

Thanks

Comment: When asking questions on SO, try to include what approaches you have already tried. SO is a forum where people help you arrive at a solution, not write complete answers for you.

Comment: I am sorry this was my first time asking the question here. I will post my approaches for my next question.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> words = ['xerox', 'trust', 'follow', 'blurb', 'maroon', 'ready', 'salad', 'yummy', 'evidence']
>>> [w for w in words if w[0] == w[-1]]
['xerox', 'trust', 'blurb', 'yummy', 'evidence']
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use unpacking in Python3:

```
s = ['xerox', 'trust', 'follow', 'blurb', 'maroon', 'ready', 'salad', 'yummy', 'evidence'] 
final_words = [''.join([a, *b, c]) for a, *b, c in s if a == c]
```

Output:

```
['xerox', 'trust', 'blurb', 'yummy', 'evidence']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code !

I am also attach the screenshot of the output of code.

```
list = ['xerox', 'trust', 'follow', 'blurb', 'maroon', 'ready', 'salad', 'yummy', 'evidence']
for i in range(0,len(list)):
  if list[i][:1]==list[i][-1:]:
    print(list[I])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you filter out words that `endswith` the first character.

```
words = ['xerox', 'trust', 'follow', 'blurb', 'maroon',
         'ready', 'salad', 'yummy', 'evidence']

result = [w for w in words if w.endswith(w[:1])]
```

This has the particular behavior that it will even work on the empty string.